# How to replace subfloor under torch-on deck

Tags: deck, roofing

A friend has a deck that is exposed to the elements, and the sub-floor is rotting. The finishing is **torch-on roofing** with a coarse granular finish.

I would like to help him replace rotted sections of the sub-floor, and any joists or beams that need replacement too. I have experience with deck framing and sub-floor replacement, but no experience with torch-on. My friend has some exeperience with torches for highway repairs.

The deck has a wooden rail with glass panels, so torching it will be a challenge.

Once the rotted subfloor is removed I will be able to inspect the framing. There is soffeting underneath.

The rotted area totals perhaps two sections of 2ft x 16 ft in an L shape around the outer corner of the deck. So a total of 2 sheets of 4x8 PT plywood would need to be cut to size and installed, replacing the rotted area. Then the repaired section would be covered by torch-on to match the rest of the deck.

How is the removal and application of torch-on best approached for this kind of repair?

Along which lines would the torch-on be cut (if at all) to get access to the sub-floor? The seams only?

Does it suffice to shield the railing, or must it be removed? The rotted area extends under the railing to the edge of the deck.

(A PVC or Vinyl replacement of the entire deck is not in the budget)

Comment: This seems a bit beyond a repair and is most likely a re-do. Torch down does not lend itself well to removal. If you torched-off the granulated sheets it would still leave a mess on the subfloor sheeting. Also I do not think you can work without removing the railings. Seems to me the railing posts would show rotting as well (not to mention the difficulty of trying to work around the posts). Then trying to patch in the torch down will be pretty ugly too. All this work and no guarantees that the finished job will be waterproof ? Best option would be to save $ up for redoing the entire deck